# "Build Warning: Layout requested does not exist"

Tags: html, layout, jekyll

The layout of the files are saved in `_layout` and one I'm trying to access is called `default.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% include head.html %}
<body>
    {{ content }}
</body>
</html>
```

2016-6-1-Assessing-The-Viability-of-Consumer-Virtual-Reality-Headsets-Head-Mounted-Displays-for-the-Treatment-of-Amblyopia.md

```
---
layout: default
title: sadsadasdasdas
categories: VR Dissertation University
---
blah blah blah
```

And sadly (even with the default post layout) - I get the following error

```
Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2016-08-28 17:01:43      Build Warning: Layout 'default' requested in _posts/2016-6-1-Assessing-The-Viability-of-Consumer-Virtual-Reality-Headsets-Head-Mounted-Displays-for-the-Treatment-of-Amblyopia.markdown does not exist.
```

Any ideas on this? Everything seems to be spelt correctly, and should all be linking up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple typo — change your `_layout` directory to `_layouts`.

Look at the [Jekyll layout guide](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/) for reference.

Comment: I might be the largest idiot ever.
Thank you do much.

Comment: @Ollie hahahahah no worries, we've all made similar mistakes before, glad I could help!